# Are there any restrictions on classes you can override with preference in di.xml

Tags: overrides, di

When overriding a class with a custom one using the di.xml, are there any restrictions on what class you can override?

I have tried overriding a class of a third party module, but it does not appear to work. This class does not implement any interface, so I thought that maybe it's only interface implementations that can be used here?

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<preference for="Amasty\Feed\Model\Export\Adapter\Csv" type="Engmaso\Feed\Model\Export\Adapter\Csv" />
</config>
```

So here I'm trying to simply add my class in place of the Amasty one, but my class is never loaded.

Comment: abstatact class ??

Comment: If interface implemented with class then, it would be great you caninterface override using preference in di.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

When you override the class make sure below changes are verified.

```
<config>
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface" type="Test\Catalog\Model\Product" />
</config>
```

and your new class should extend existing class.
please see below example

```
<?php
namespace Test\Catalog\Model;

class Product extends \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product
{
// code
}
```